# Display Temperature value with air pressure and altitude

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

Iam displaying my temperature sensor values in text view and also displaying air pressure from air pressure sensor with altitude in another two text view
the problem is that the first text view display air pressure instead of displaying temperature and the other text views display correct values of air pressure and altitude  and i named the text view id correct but when i run the app it dosnt display temperature in first text view in the same activity and if i separate them in two activities it work good but i want to dislapy them in same activity and this is my code

```
  public class TemperatureActivity extends Activity
    implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private boolean isSensorPresent;
private TextView mTemperatureValue;
private TextView mPressureValue;
private TextView mAltitudeValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSensorManager =
            (SensorManager)this.getSystemService
                    (Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mTemperatureValue =
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperaturetext);
    if(mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor
            (Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) != null) {
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor
                (Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
        isSensorPresent = true;
    } else {
        mTemperatureValue.setText("Ambient Temperature Sensor is not available!");
        isSensorPresent = false;
    }


    mPressureValue =
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pressuretext);
    mAltitudeValue =
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.altitudetext);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if(mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor
            (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE) != null) {
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor
                (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
        isSensorPresent = true;
    } else {
        isSensorPresent = false;
        mPressureValue.setText("Pressure Sensor is not available!");
        mAltitudeValue.setText("Cannot calculate altitude, as pressure 
     Sensor is not available!");
    }





}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(isSensorPresent) {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(isSensorPresent) {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    mTemperatureValue.setText("Temperature in degree Celsius is " + 
   event.values[0]);

   float pressure = event.values[0];
    mPressureValue.setText("Pressure in mbar is " +
            pressure);
    float altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude
            (SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,
                    pressure);
    mAltitudeValue.setText("Current altitude is " +
            altitude);

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

  }



}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just so you know-  the temperature sensor rarely exists, and when it does it doesn't do what you think-  it shows the internal temperature of the phone, which will be MUCH higher due to heat from the battery and processor.

Comment: i have temp sensor and i read it value in my application  if i used one text view in activity and i want to display in that activity too the air pressure in another text view .when i run it it display air pressure in both text views(same value). if i removed displaying air pressure  code from my app it work good displaying temperature i think sensor manager conflict between two values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    mTemperatureValue.setText("Temperature in degree Celsius is " + 
   event.values[0]);

   float pressure = event.values[0];
    mPressureValue.setText("Pressure in mbar is " +
            pressure);
    float altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude
            (SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,
                    pressure);
    mAltitudeValue.setText("Current altitude is " +
            altitude);

}
```

Completely broken.  Every sensor event, you're writing the same value to multiple fields.  You get one event per sensor.  You should update the temperature only when you get a temperature event, the pressure only when you get a pressure event, etc.